# Javascript half works locally, fully works on code pen

Tags: javascript, html

Been racking my brains trying to figure this out. I've tried adding $( document ).ready(function() { and closing it again around the script but not joy.

It's a simple filter. Supposed to show / hide div elements depending on the button. The script adds 'active' to the button clicked and removes it from the other buttons.

It works exactly as intended on Code Pen. However, when running it locally or on a server, the filter works fine, 'active' is added to the button clicked, but 'active' is not removed from the last button and keeps stacking (ie if I click snowdonia 4 times, the class 'active' is applied 4 times. If I then click tryfan, active is applied correctly but not removed from the previous button)

The code I'm using is below. Any help would be much appreciated. The Javascript is EXACTLY as it appears in my filter.js file

```js
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}
        var header = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn-filter");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  if (current.length > 0) { 
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.filterDiv {
    display: none;

    /* Hidden by default */
}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
    display: block;
}

.btn-filter {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #91227e;
    border: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #91227e;
}

.active,
.btn-filter:hover {
    background-color: #91227e;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
                <div id="myBtnContainer">
                    <button class="btn-filter active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
                    <button class="btn-filter" onclick="filterSelection('snowdon')"> Snowdon</button>
                    <button class="btn-filter" onclick="filterSelection('tryfan')"> Tryfan</button>
                    <button class="btn-filter" onclick="filterSelection('glyder')"> Glyder</button>
                </div>
```

Here are the scripts I have linked in the html file:

And here a link to a working version in codepen: https://codepen.io/dan-anderton-the-sasster/pen/vYgWdER

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Also, could you reduce your code sample to a [mcve]; as it stands it's a little cluttered with some repetition that's not going to help folks find a soution.

Comment: No, no errors at all.

Comment: try to use `window.addEventListener('load', function() {//this initialization});`

Comment: I came across that when I was trying to figure this out on my own and gave it a go. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Lot of places for weird stuff to happen in this code. Don't one line the `if` statements and drop the `{}`, you're asking for trouble. And you could really simplify things without all these placeholder arrays. Just do the manipulation directly with array methods like `.filter()`, `.map()`, `.reduce()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but more of a suggestion. But with your localhost environment are you also including the necessary files which are being used in the codepen example?
IE: jquery?

I cannot tell from the example you have provided, but a link to the codepen would be useful.

TRY - you may need to tweak slightly to fit your html, as I cannot view this:

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-filter");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("activated");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Apologies tried posting the info you asked for and it looked a mess. Added to the main question.

Comment: Hi Dan. I have updated my answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that didn't work either. I did manage to get it working though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a CSS conflict with the active tag between my code and bootstrap. Changing the class to be applied to the current button solved the problem. So changing it from active to active-filter in this case and then styling accordingly.

Thanks everyone for looking at it for me.

Answer (score 0):

VERY similar issue. No idea why this worked, but someone told me to see what the settings where on Codepen and I noticed it was adding this stylesheet to the project:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">`

So I added that to my `<head>`, and the javascript worked instantly. Weird.